# Unable to publish nunit test results to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, tfsbuild, .net-core, nunit-3.0

I'm setting up Continuous integration in Team Services. The solution currently has a couple of unit test  projects. All projects in the solution are .NET core projects.

The out of the box test runner in the build definition isn't pick up any of the unit tests projects (yes, the test assembly wildcards are setup correctly), so I've resorted to writing a batch file that executes `dotnet test`. After the command runs, an XML file is written to the disk which contains the results. I'm using the publish results step and pointing to that file so that the test results will show up in the build output. I've set the "Test Result Format" field to NUnit, but that step produces the following warning:

```
Invalid results file. Please make sure the Test Result Format field in the task matches the result format of the file: C:\<path to file>\TestResult.xml
```

Has anyone else been able to publish NUnit test results that were generated from running the `dotnet test` command in Team Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because VSTS does not support NUnit3 format. You can consider to use the workarounds mentioned by jirisykora83 and CharliePoole in this question: [Support NUnit2 format](https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-test-nunit/issues/75).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct, because it's the only thing that made sense. I looked into what it would take and it's too much effort IMO. Fortunately I don't have that many unit tests yet, so I just switched over to xunit and it's working fine. I'm still having to execute the tests with a batch script, but I can output to XML and then use another step to publish those results. Do you know where I can report, or "vote", on an issue to get NUnit3 supported? This seems like a very large hole.

Comment: @BrianBall VSTS User Voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Comment: Thanks! I added my suggestion here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15864978-nunit-3-results-format-does-not-appear-to-be-suppo

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to run your own batch script to run tests. Even though you have set in the batch script that `dotnet test` should generate NUnit file, but in publish task it may not be NUnit option. You can give a try with JUnit Format or XUnit Format in the *Test Result Format*.

[image]

Comment: I went back and tried with all of the format options. None of them work. I checked in a test result file generated locally, and create a one-step build that published the results in that file. All of the options generated the same error. I've looked at the XML file and it does appear to be in the nunit format.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to publish my test results by using dotnet test task in combination with Publish Test Results. 
The build configuration looks like this:

1. In the dotnet test task, add additional argument `--logger:trx`
   [image]
2. Add a Publish Test Result task after the test task, and configure it with:

> Test result format: VSTest

and

> Test results files: ***.trx

[image]